# How to get value from Sub Form

Tags: joomla-3.6, subform

I want to embed a simple slideshow to my template, and I want to use subform to make easier to change the image.

This is the code I use to call the child xml file

```
<field name="slideshow_items" type="subform" formsource="templates/jomlamaster/admin/subform/slideshow.xml" min="1" max="4" multiple="true" layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table" groupByFieldset="true" label="Subform Field" description="Subform Field Description" />
```

and this is the content of slideshow.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
<fieldset name="fieldset" label="Slideshow">
<field name="slideshow_img" type="media" directory="" label="Slideshow item" description="Choose an image slideshow"/>
<field name="slideshow_title" type="text" class="inputbox" label="Slideshow text" size="40" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

This is what I get when print_r($slideshow_items);

```
stdClass Object
(
    [slideshow_items0] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [slideshow_img] =&gt; images/slideshow/img0.jpg
            [slideshow_text] =&gt; Title 1
        )

    [slideshow_items1] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [slideshow_img] =&gt; images/slideshow/img1.jpg
            [slideshow_text] =&gt; Title 2
        )

    [slideshow_items2] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [slideshow_img] =&gt; images/slideshow/img2.jpg
            [slideshow_text] =&gt; Title 3
        )

    [slideshow_items3] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [slideshow_img] =&gt; images/slideshow/img3.jpg
            [slideshow_text] =&gt; Title 4
        )

)
```

How can I parse the values above so I can use them for slideshow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my solution. If there's any better solution please let me know

```
<?php foreach ($slideshow_items as $item) : ?>
  <div class="slideshow">
    <img src="<?php echo $item->slideshow_img; ?>" />
    <p class="slideshow_text">
      <?php echo $item->slideshow_text; ?>
    </p>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: that is correct solution ;) 
only thing, I would check whether property exist, something like:
`echo empty($item->slideshow_img) ? '' : $item->slideshow_img;`

Answer (score 3):

Sub Form Fields data save as JSON format so first need to "json_decode()" this to get the data then run foreach look to get data.

```
<?php $slideshow_items= json_decode($this->item->slideshow_items); ?>

<?php foreach ($slideshow_items as $item) : ?>
<div class="slideshow">
<img src="<?php echo $item->slideshow_img; ?>" />
<p class="slideshow_text">
  <?php echo $item->slideshow_text; ?>
</p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you need to get just one field names' value:

```
use Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper;

$items = ArrayHelper::getColumn((array) $params->get('subformName'), 'fieldName');
```

Comment: How do you add or call the `Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper;`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Bootstrap Carousel. this works for me.

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <?php foreach ($slideshow_items as $item => $value) :?>
            <div class="item<?php echo ($item=='slideshow_items0') ? ' active': ''; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $value->slideshow_img;?>">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption>">
                <p><?php echo $value->slideshow_text;?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

if someone wants to improve or provide best practices code is welcome.