# Retrieving data from Joomla! Subform form field type

Tags: php, joomla-3.6, xml

I'm trying to retrieving data from Joomla! Subform form field type,

Here what I have:

```
<fieldset name="item_lists" label="Item List">      
        <field name="ilist" type="subform"
            formsource="list.xml"
            label="Add Item" 
            description="" 
            multiple="true"
        />
</fieldset>
```

Here is the list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
    <field name="ilist_add" 
        type="media" 
        label="Add Item"
        directory="" 
    />
</form>
```

Now how can I load above repeatable field images with Unorder list like

```
<ul>
<li><img src="image1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="image2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="image3.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="image4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried this -> http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17146/how-to-get-value-from-sub-form